# struts2 - how to expose an action class' field's subclass for conversion to JSON?

Tags: struts2, struts

```java
class ReportAction{
   private Report report;
   String reportType;
   ...
   public String execute(){
      switch (reportType){
        case "user" : someService.getUserReport();
        ....

      }
   }    
}
```

Now, the service returns subclasses of `Report`, depending upon the type of reports asked. When I use the **json** result type, and specify '`report`' to be converted to **JSON**, I assume that only the fields declared in Report will be converted to **JSON**, not the fields of the actual subclass reference that '`report`' holds. Each subclass of `Report` has extra fields, and I want them to be included when the '`report`' field is converted to **JSON**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've assumed wrong. You can use plain Object when you serialize that you get all the properties. This is because the serialization does not use the type blindly rather it uses reflection to determine properties, after all it needs to recursively descend and polymorphism being common use with OO this should be the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. I underestimated the power of Reflection